# Finding an Inverse Laplace Transform

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, inverse-laplace

Given the differential equation $y'' +2y'+5y = 3e^{-x}\sin(x)$, with $y(0) = 0$, $y'(0) = 3$, I'm asked to use Laplace transforms to find the solution.

So I used the tables to get the following:

- $\begin{align}\mathcal{L}[y]''&=s^2\mathcal{L}[y] -sy(0)-y'(0)\\&=s^2\mathcal{L}[y]-3\end{align}$
- $\begin{align}\mathcal{L}[y']&=s\mathcal{L}[y]-y(0)\\&=s\mathcal{L}[y]\end{align}$

Here's where it gets sketchy:

$$\begin{align}\mathcal{L}\left[e^{-x}\sin(x)\right] &= \mathcal{L}\left[e^{-x}\cdot\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}\right]\enspace \text{(by Euler's formula)}\\&=\mathcal{L}\left[\frac{e^{x(-1+i)}-e^{x(-1-i)}}{2i}\right]\\&=\frac{1}{2i}\left(\mathcal{L}\left[e^{x(-1+i)}\right]-\mathcal{L}\left[e^{x(-1-i)}\right]\right) \\&=\frac{1}{2i}\left(\frac{1}{s-i+1}-\frac{1}{s+i+1}\right)\end{align}$$

After taking the transform of both sides of the equation and subbing in we have:
$$s^2\mathcal{L}[y]-3+2s\mathcal{L}[y]+5\mathcal{L}[y]=\frac{3}{2i}\left(\frac{1}{s-i+1}-\frac{1}{s+i+1}\right)$$
$$\begin{align}&\implies\mathcal{L}[y]\left(s^2+2s+5\right)-3=\frac{3}{2i}\left(\frac{1}{s-i+1}-\frac{1}{s+i+1}\right)\\&\implies\mathcal{L}[y]=\frac{3}{2i(s^2+2s+5)}\cdot\left(\frac{s+i+1-s+i-1}{(s-i+1)(s+i+1)}\right)+3\end{align}\\=\frac{3}{s^2+2s+3}\left(\frac{1}{s^2+s+2}\right)$$
$$\implies y = \mathcal{L^{-1}}\left[\frac{1}{s^4+3s^3+7s^2+7s+6}\right]$$

1. Is my reasoning here correct? It's so convoluted that I feel like I've missed an easier way.
2. If it *is* correct, how do I find the inverse transform I've ended up with? I've tried using the tables but I can't figure out which formula to apply.

Comment: Why not just use item 19 from http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Laplace_Table.aspx? This gets rid of all the imaginary stuff, which could lead to algebra errors. You shoud get $$Y(s) = \dfrac{3 \left(s^2+2 s+3\right)}{\left(s^2+2 s+2\right) \left(s^2+2 s+5\right)}$$

Comment: Can you split$$\frac3{(s^2+2s+3)(s^2+s+2)}$$into partial fractions?

Comment: @Moo , I was operating off of a different set of tables which didn't have that identity. Thanks!

Comment: @user170231 Thanks for pointing that out. I tend to try and overcomplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\mathcal{L}\left[e^{-x}\sin(x)\right] = \frac{1}{(s+1)^2+1}$$

1)Take a look at the table here [Laplace Transform Table](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/pdf/Laplace_Table.pdf)

2) Use fraction decomposition instead of convolution theorem. Or the table.
$$g(s)=\frac{3}{s^2+2s+5}$$

$$g(s)=\frac{3}{(s+1)^2+4} \implies g(t)=\frac 32e^{-t}\sin (2t)$$

---

Decompose the fraction as:
$$f(s)= \frac{1}{(s^2+2s+2)(s^2+2s+5)}$$
$$f(s)= \frac{1}{((s+1)^2+1)((s+1)^2+4)}$$
Substitute $u=s+1$
$$f(u)= \frac{1}{(u^2+1)(u^2+4)}$$
$$f(u)= \frac 13\frac{1}{(u^2+1)}- \frac 13\frac{1}{(u^2+4)}$$
$$f(s)= \frac 13\frac{1}{((s+1)^2+1)}- \frac 13\frac{1}{((s+1)^2+4)}$$
Apply inverse Laplace transform.
$$f(t)= \frac 13 e^{-t}\sin (t)- \frac 16e^{-t}\sin (2t)$$
Finally 
$$y(t)=g(t)+3f(t)$$
$$\boxed {y(t)= e^{-t}\sin (t)+ e^{-t}\sin (2t)}$$